# How to resolve problem with resizing video in aframe for mobile?

Tags: aframe

I don't know how to resolve problem with resizing video in A-Frame 0.8.2 for mobile. Watch the black ring and yellow model on the pictures. Circle and model change the shape if I transform width and height of video. I want to get static form of model and another objects.

```
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" 
         arjs="debugUIEnabled: false; 
         sourceType: webcam; 
         detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; 
         matrixCodeType: 3x3">

<a-entity camera>
         <a-entity cursor="fuse: false; "
         position="0 0 -1"
         geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
         material="color: black; shader: flat">
                  <a-animation begin="click" 
                               easing="ease-in" 
                               attribute="scale"
                               fill="forwards" 
                               from="0.2 0.2 0.2" 
                               to="1 1 1" dur="150">                                        
                   </a-animation>

         </a-entity>
```